# Wait for modal window to close and then execute the following lines in javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a modal Window which pops up and wait for 5 seconds and then closes.
The code is as follows

```
  function callMe()
  {
//alert("entering");
  $("#dialog").dialog({
         modal: true,
         //title: "Confirm",
         resizable: false,
         width: 300,
         height: 150,
         open: function (event, ui) 
         {
               setTimeout(function () { $("#dialog").dialog("close");}, 5000);

         },
         buttons: {
             Ok: function () {
                // $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Ok
             },
             Cancel: function () {
                // $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Cancel
             }
         }

     });
         alert("Some Text");
  }
```

callMe() function is called on load of the HTML file. Here I want to show the alert message "Some Text" after the modal window closes in 5 second. But every time when I run this it shows both the modal window and alert box together. I want the modal window to display first , wait for 5 sec and then show the alert box.I tried using sleep but its still coming the same way.

Comment: You just need to call alert inside setTimeout function like this setTimeout(function () { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); alert("Some Text");}, 5000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

```
function callMe()
  {
//alert("entering");
    $("#dialog").dialog({
         modal: true,
         //title: "Confirm",
         resizable: false,
         width: 300,
         height: 150,
         open: function (event, ui) 
         {
               setTimeout(function () { $("#dialog").dialog("close");}, 5000);

         },
         buttons: {
             Ok: function () {
                // $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Ok
             },
             Cancel: function () {
                // $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Cancel
             }
         },
         close: function(){
             alert("Some Text");
         }
    });


     $('#dialog').on('dialogclose', function(event) {
        alert('Some Text');
     });
  }
```

1. USE "close" method
2. use on dialogueClose event both examples are given in code above

Answer (score 1):

It would be nicer if you can tell us what plugin you use for the dialog. I'm guessing the dialog has a `close` option that accepts a function. So try this:

```
     ...
     open: function (event, ui) 
     {
           setTimeout(function () { $("#dialog").dialog("close");}, 5000);
     },
     close: function() {
        alert("Some Text");
     },
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the alert inside the setTimeout, just after you close the window.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 open: function (event, ui) 
 {
       setTimeout(function () { 
           $("#dialog").dialog("close");
           alert("Some Text");
       }, 5000);

 },
```